# Assigning a Variable Generic NEW Value by Pressing a Postgres Trigger

Tags: postgresql

In the trigger body, how can I get a value of `NEW` by the field name?

This is what I want to do:

```
some_key = "some_column";

value := NEW[some_key];
```

Comment: This is not possible. May be you could explain the problem you're trying to solve, instead of your impossible solution to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dynamic SQL like this:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT $1.%I', some_key) INTO value USING NEW;
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, thank you very much.
I managed to solve the problem.

See part of the code.
`code`
    FOR ri IN
        SELECT ordinal_position, column_name, data_type
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE
            table_schema = quote_ident(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA)
        AND table_name = quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME) 
  AND column_name = quote_ident(nmpk)  
        ORDER BY ordinal_position
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'SELECT ($1).' || ri.column_name || '::text' INTO t USING NEW;
        idValue := t;
    END LOOP;

Comment: If the answer is correct, you might accept it. Concatenating column names with `||` is a bad idea because of the risk of SQL injection. Use the `format` function like I did in my answer.